# How to catch exception from VLC?

Tags: python, try-catch, vlc

I have problem with catching exception from VLC. Instead of printing my text I get information like:

- [00007f0988001690] filesystem stream error: cannot open file
  /home/user/recording.mp3 (No such file or directory)
- [0000557838609be0] main input error: Your input can't be opened
- [0000557838609be0] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL
  'file:///home/user/recording.mp3'. Check the log for details.

Here is my code:

```
from vlc import MediaPlayer

x = MediaPlayer('recording.mp3')

def play_sound():
    try:
        x.play()
    except:
        print('Cannot play sound.')

play_sound()
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You could try looking at https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/ . `python-vlc` is merely a python binding for `libVLC`. So it's not python that's giving the errors. It's the `libVLC` binaries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great answer, but does me as a workaround until one turns up.

I cannot trap the error as desired, but I can read the logs and act on that

There is discussion at https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/fgymq4/import_vlc_error_python/ on turning logging on in code, but none of that worked for me.

Instead, start vlc and pipe standard error to a file using

```
your_python_script.py &> yourlog_file.txt
```

Then use [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) to observe that file and take action.

Not great. Better than anything else I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following way to get playback errors natively with vlcs event_manager callback functions. Here is my working code:

```
def callback_from_player(self, event: vlc.Event, *args):
  logging.debug('callback called: %s, from %s', event.type, args[0])
  # continue with your code here, I am starting a new thread at this point.
  # one cannot call vlc library functions within the event callback function.


def play(self):
  instance: vlc.Instance = vlc.Instance() 

  list_player: vlc.MediaListPlayer = instance.media_list_player_new()
  list_player.set_playback_mode(vlc.PlaybackMode.loop)
  media_player: vlc.MediaPlayer = list_player.get_media_player()
 
  # the crutial line:
  media_player.event_manager().event_attach(
    vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEncounteredError, 
    self.callback_from_player, "media_player")

  media: vlc.Media = instance.media_new(self.url)
  media_list: vlc.MediaList = instance.media_list_new([])
  list_player.set_media_list(media_list)
  media_list.add_media(media) 
  list_player.play()
```